# Why does scraper stop at the 12th image?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I have to scrape all the products from this website's shop ( https://bewellstore.ro/shop/), but my code stops at the 12th photo. I have made a version for websites with multiple shop pages where I take them all in a `for` loop, but since here it's only one page I thought that isn't necessary.
Any idea why my code stops at the 12th product?

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

folder = 'beWell_images'
os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)

root_folder = os.getcwd()

baseurl = 'https://bewellstore.ro/shop/'

# an array for all the product links
product_links = [] 

# going through all the pages of the shop
url = 'https://bewellstore.ro/shop/'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

product_list = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'loop-product-inner')
print (product_list)
    # taking all the links to each product page
for item in product_list:
    for link in item.find_all('a', href=True, class_='woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link'):
        product_links.append(link['href'])
            # appending the links previously taken to the array
print(product_links)
product_items_list = []

i = 0
d = {}  # use as set() 

os.chdir(folder)

for link_test in product_links:

    r = requests.get(link_test)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    
    title = soup.find('h1', class_='product_title').text.strip()
    price = soup.find('p', class_ = 'price').text.strip()
    header = soup.find('div', class_ = 'woocommerce-product-details__short-description').text.strip()
    sku  = soup.find('span', class_ = 'sku').text.strip()
    categories = soup.find('div' , class_ = 'posted_in').text.strip()
    description = soup.find('div', class_ = 'cell large-6').text.strip()
    brand = soup.find('div', class_ = 'tabs-panel').text.strip()

    images = soup.select('.wp-post-image')
    
    # --- before `for`-loop ---
    
    downloaded = []
    
    # --- `for`-loop ---
    for image in images:
        link = image['src']
        if link in d:
            name = d[link]
            downloaded.append(name)
        else:
            i += 1
            name = str(i) +'img.jpg'
            d[link] = name
            print('link:', link)
            print('name:', name)
            print('---')
            # here i am adding the .jpg and saving the images
            with open(name, 'wb') as f:
                im = requests.get(link)
                #print("URMEAZA DEBUG: {}".format(im))
                f.write(im.content)
            downloaded.append(name)
            
    # --- after `for`-loop ---
    
    # storing all the infos about this product 

    img_str = ''
    if len(downloaded) > 1:
        for index, img in enumerate(downloaded):
            if index == len(downloaded)-1:
                img_str = img_str + img
            else:
                img_str = img_str + img + '/'
    else: 
       img_str = downloaded[0] 


    product = {
        'sku': sku,
        'base_image': img_str,
        'small_image': img_str,
        'thumbnail_image': img_str,
        'additional_images': img_str,
        'product_type': 'simple',
        'attribute_set_code': 'Default',
        'categories': categories.replace('Categorii: ','').replace(', ', '/'),
        'name' : title,
        'description': description,
        'short_description': header,
        'price' : price[0:5]
    }
    product_items_list.append(product)
    
os.chdir(root_folder)
# os.chdir('output')
df = pd.DataFrame(product_items_list)
print(df)
df.to_csv('beWell.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because this webpage uses pagination (with 12 products per page) and each page gets loaded only when you scroll. You will have to use `selenium` to scroll the page.

#### But if you only want to use `beautifulsoup` then there is a work around.

- The URL for each page looks like this

  ```
  https://bewellstore.ro/shop/page/<page_no>/
  ```
- Example:

  ```
  1st page: https://bewellstore.ro/shop/page/1/
  2nd page: https://bewellstore.ro/shop/page/2/
  ```

###### You could make a request to each of the above URLs and scrape your data using `beautifulsoup`.

Comment: isn't it in one page?

Comment: No. It looks like one page but you'll see that **only when you scroll**, new products are displayed. You can see it under Network tab in DevTools, that whenever you scroll by a certain amount a new request is being made to the page URLs I mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for the all pages

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv 
from datetime import datetime

results = []

page_number = 1
import requests
product_links = [] 
headers = {
    'authority': 'bewellstore.ro',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://bewellstore.ro/shop/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': 'fp_session=new; mc_landing_site=https://bewellstore.ro/shop/; _omappvp=i5rIyW2xsMFKIu3uhQtmFj1TN9jw7aKjO8dgy3SVvWMhAj30NvKFrBXfJLe3dQK6ZdbB4FezbrwFWPGLdKrsj1A1vqN2PRLI; _omappvs=1634795539874; _clck=1f7zptk|1|evr|0; _ga=GA1.2.2117949575.1634795541; _gid=GA1.2.1155690725.1634795541; _fbp=fb.1.1634795541140.1266696245; PHPSESSID=94b6b1996b0b5e831d898c192b4bca06; _clsk=2489zg|1634795542054|1|1|e.clarity.ms/collect; yith_wcwl_session_d235bd7d63b3a120c05ba3c90256789a=%7B%22session_id%22%3A%222e40c31b1503902767c5327edd3cf926%22%2C%22session_expiration%22%3A1637387542%2C%22session_expiring%22%3A1637383942%2C%22cookie_hash%22%3A%2249a81940bd8d39b2f894021c16333e6f%22%7D; omSeen-dwf9rgtvzzrhqylccaag=1634795583943; om-dwf9rgtvzzrhqylccaag=1634795585931; _omra={"dwf9rgtvzzrhqylccaag":"click"}; cookie_notice_accepted=true; ls_smartpush=fdfbe0ffe7800007',
}

while True:
    response = requests.get(f'https://bewellstore.ro/shop/page/{page_number}/', headers=headers)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        break
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    product_list = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'loop-product-inner')
    # print (product_list)  

    for item in product_list:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True, class_='woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link'):
            product_links.append(link['href'])
            print('Addedn link in product_links list :', link['href'])

    product_items_list = []
    i = 0
    d = {}

    for link_test in product_links:

        r = requests.get(link_test)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

        title = soup.find('h1', class_='product_title').text.strip()
        price = soup.find('p', class_ = 'price').text.strip()
        header = soup.find('div', class_ = 'woocommerce-product-details__short-description').text.strip()
        sku  = soup.find('span', class_ = 'sku').text.strip()
        categories = soup.find('div' , class_ = 'posted_in').text.strip()
        description = soup.find('div', class_ = 'cell large-6').text.strip()
        brand = soup.find('div', class_ = 'tabs-panel').text.strip()

        images = soup.select('.wp-post-image')

        downloaded = []

        for image in images:
            link = image['src']
            if link in d:
                name = d[link]
                downloaded.append(name)
            else:
                i += 1
                name = str(i) +'img.jpg'
                d[link] = name
                print('link:', link)
                print('name:', name)
                print('---')
            # here i am adding the .jpg and saving the images
            with open(name, 'wb') as f:
                im = requests.get(link)
                #print("URMEAZA DEBUG: {}".format(im))
                f.write(im.content)
                downloaded.append(name)


        img_str = ''
        if len(downloaded) > 1:
            for index, img in enumerate(downloaded):
                if index == len(downloaded)-1:
                    img_str = img_str + img
                else:
                    img_str = img_str + img + '/'
        else: 
            img_str = downloaded[0] 


        product = {
        'sku': sku,
        'base_image': img_str,
        'small_image': img_str,
        'thumbnail_image': img_str,
        'additional_images': img_str,
        'product_type': 'simple',
        'attribute_set_code': 'Default',
        'categories': categories.replace('Categorii: ','').replace(', ', '/'),
        'name' : title,
        'description': description,
        'short_description': header,
        'price' : price[0:5]
        }
        product_items_list.append(product)
                    

    page_number += 1


df = pd.DataFrame(product_items_list)
print(df)
df.to_csv('beWell.csv', index=False)
```